# Validación de duplicidad de campos mediante consultas PHP

Tags: php

Al validar la creación de un nuevo usuario, antes de realizar el INSERT en la tabla users, realizo 2 consultas para comprobar si existe el nombre y el email.

Si hay coincidencias en el nombre, funciona OK.
Si hay coincidencias en el email, no funciona.
Si hay coincidencias en los dos campos, encuentra coincidencia en el email.

Gracias.

Adjunto el código:

```
/* Creamos la conexión BD */
    include("../php/conectionBD.php");

    /* Validaciones... */

        /* Eliminamos la variable en sesión para el control de errores */
        unset($SESSION["errorCreateAccount"]);

        /* Comprobamos si el nombre de usuario existe */
        $queryUsername = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?;");
        $queryUsername->bindParam(1, $username);
        $queryUsername->execute();

        if ($queryUsername->rowCount() > 0){
            /* Crear variable de Sesión para el error */
            $SESSION["errorCreateAccount"] = 'ErrorUsername';
            /* Redireccionamos a la página de registro */
            header('location:../pages/createAccount1.php');
        }

        /* Comprobamos si el email existe */
        $queryEmail = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?;");
        $queryEmail->bindParam(1, $email);
        $queryEmail->execute();

        if ($queryEmail->rowCount() > 0){
            /* Crear variable de Sesión para el error */
            $SESSION["errorCreateAccount"] = 'ErrorEmail';
            /* Redireccionamos a la página de registro */
            header('location:../pages/createAccount2.php');
        }

    /* Fin Validaciones... */
```

Comment: ¿Conseguiste solucionar el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te e modificado el codigo, debes definir los tipos de parametros que vas a ligar junto a tu sentencia, en este caso `string`.

Tambien tienes un error en las dos sentencias prepare al final as añadido un ; en `= ?;"` debes tambien eliminar el `;`

Para comprobar si existe algun registro e utilizado `store_result()`, transfiere un conjunto de resultados desde una sentencia preparada.

Para comprobar si existen algun resultado, utilizo `num_rows`

Por ultimo, tambien es importante nada más acabamos con nuestra sentencia preparada, cerrar dicha sentencia, simplemente con `close()`

```
/* Creamos la conexión BD */
    include("../php/conectionBD.php");

    /* Validaciones... */

        /* Eliminamos la variable en sesión para el control de errores */
        unset($SESSION["errorCreateAccount"]);

        /* Comprobamos si el nombre de usuario existe */
        $queryUsername = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?");
        $queryUsername->bindParam("s", $username);
        $queryUsername->execute();
        $queryUsername->store_result();

        if ($queryUsername->num_rows ===1){
            /* Crear variable de Sesión para el error */
            $SESSION["errorCreateAccount"] = 'ErrorUsername';
            /* Redireccionamos a la página de registro */
            header('location:../pages/createAccount1.php');
        } $queryUsername->close();

        /* Comprobamos si el email existe */
        $queryEmail = $db->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?");
        $queryEmail->bindParam("s", $email);
        $queryEmail->execute();
        $queryEmail->store_result();

        if ($queryEmail->num_rows===1){
            /* Crear variable de Sesión para el error */
            $SESSION["errorCreateAccount"] = 'ErrorEmail';
            /* Redireccionamos a la página de registro */
            header('location:../pages/createAccount2.php');
        } $queryEmail->close();

    /* Fin Validaciones... */
```

Answer (score 0):

Mirando la [documentación](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) veo que una cosa que puede estar mal es el `1` que pones en el `bindParam`. Prueba de sustituirlo por `"s"` --> Importante que esté en `""`

Otro posible problema es que no se hace el `close()` del statement:

```
$queryUsername->close();
```

Igualmente, porqué no realizar una única consulta a BD, te ahorras consultas y tiempo:

```
   $queryUsername = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? OR `email` = ?;");
   $queryUsername->bindParam("ss", $username, $email);
```

Comment: Miguel Coll, estás respondiendo en SOes, por lo tanto la respuesta debería ir en el mismo idioma que comparte el sitio.

Comment: @OscarR. Disculpadme; es la manía.

Comment: He probado el cambio pero no me funciona: devuelve un error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031.

De todas maneras, necesito evaluar si tiene una coincidencio u otra para mostrar diferentes errores, por eso no lo he puesto en la misma query. Gracias

Comment: Me devuelve el mismo error cuando hago el close();